# multithread with asyncTasck

Tags: android, multithreading

I am making an app that uses AsyncTask and I want it to use two thread that one of them is asyncTask class and another one is thread class (this is in asyncTask),and the second thread works when I press start button. I want them works all together. I ran the app and asyncTask thread works fine but when I press button to start second thread that is in synckTask thread , unfortunately the app stopped .
here is the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Thread thread;
private Button btnStart;
private TextView textView;
private Async a;
int i=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textEdit);
    btnStart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(onStart);

    a=new Async();
    a.execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public class Async extends AsyncTask< String, Long , Void >{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        textView.setText("has started ... ");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... values) {

        thread=new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(i<6) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                            Log.w(" onPostExecute ", String.valueOf(i));
                            i++;
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                super.run();
            }
        };

        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 12 ; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("count index in background ", String.valueOf(i));         
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    }
}

private View.OnClickListener onStart=new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        thread.start();

    }

};
```

}

please guide me how can I fix it for working fine...

thanks alot...

and here is its log:

```
03-17 07:35:35.913: D/libEGL(1113): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
```

03-17 07:35:35.943: D/(1113): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a154d20, tid 1113

03-17 07:35:35.963: D/libEGL(1113): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so

03-17 07:35:35.963: D/libEGL(1113): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so

03-17 07:35:36.133: W/EGL_emulation(1113): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

03-17 07:35:36.133: I/count index in background(1113): 0

03-17 07:35:36.144: D/OpenGLRenderer(1113): Enabling debug mode 0

03-17 07:35:36.404: I/count index in background(1113): 1

03-17 07:35:36.661: I/count index in background(1113): 2

03-17 07:35:36.865: I/count index in background(1113): 3

03-17 07:35:37.068: I/count index in background(1113): 4

03-17 07:35:37.272: I/count index in background(1113): 5

03-17 07:35:37.480: I/count index in background(1113): 6

03-17 07:35:37.683: I/count index in background(1113): 7

03-17 07:35:37.891: I/count index in background(1113): 8

03-17 07:35:38.223: I/count index in background(1113): 9

03-17 07:35:38.631: I/count index in background(1113): 10

03-17 07:35:38.837: I/count index in background(1113): 11

03-17 07:35:41.403: D/AndroidRuntime(1113): Shutting down VM

03-17 07:35:41.403: W/dalvikvm(1113): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)

03-17 07:35:41.443: E/AndroidRuntime(1113): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-17 07:35:41.443: E/AndroidRuntime(1113): java.lang.NullPointerException

03-17 07:35:41.443: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at com.example.asynctasckdemo.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:104)

03-17 07:35:41.443: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)

03-17 07:35:41.443: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)

03-17 07:35:41.443: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)

03-17 07:35:41.443: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

03-17 07:35:41.443: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

03-17 07:35:41.443: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)

03-17 07:35:41.443: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

03-17 07:35:41.443: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

03-17 07:35:41.443: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

03-17 07:35:41.443: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

03-17 07:35:41.443: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Can you share the log error when app stops?

Comment: Mike M thanks for your ansewer.I used onProgressUpdate() but it doesn't work. I want both of them threads ,work together.

Comment: The onProgressUpdate method is never called. You must manually invoke it with `publishProgress`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29 And since it is never run, `thread` has not been assigned a value (and is null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12 ; i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
            publishProgress();//try calling this<------------------------------
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("count index in background ", String.valueOf(i));         
    }

    return null;
}
```